# Java Nested Do-While Loops

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

So I have created this program that is suppose to compare two rectangles, a reference rectangle and a test rectangle to check if the test is within the reference, or the test is overlapping the reference, or if they share a boundary, or if they are distinct.

My program must read in a reference rectangle first and then the test rectangle, but after the program completes the user should be able to choose whether to repeat either the whole program and enter a new reference rectangle or to repeat just the part where they enter the test rectangle.

I created a large reference while loop that encompassed the second testing while loop and made them have different repeatInt variables. I am not sure where my issue is because when the user enters 2 the program correctly restarts at the testing rectangle input portion, but when they enter 1 the program again restarts at the testing input portion when it should go back to the beginning to the reference input portion and run the whole program again.

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMyRectangle2D {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    MyRectangle2D refrec = new MyRectangle2D();
    MyRectangle2D testrec = new MyRectangle2D();

    double refx;
    double refy;
    double refwidth;
    double refheight;

    double testx;
    double testy;
    double testwidth;
    double testheight;

    double pointx;
    double pointy;

    int repeatInt = 1;
    int repeatInt2 = 1;

    boolean ContinueRefWidthLoop = true;
    boolean ContinueRefHeightLoop = true;
    boolean ContinueTestWidthLoop = true;
    boolean ContinueTestHeightLoop = true;

    System.out.println("This program will ask you to enter the center coordinates, height, and width of the reference rectangle which will be the reference for the following comparisons with an additional test rectangle and test point. The program will be able to tell you if the point you enter is within the reference rectangle, it will also test the test rectangle to see if it is either contained, overlapping, abut, or distinct with the reference rectangle");

    //Reference loop for rectangle
    while(repeatInt == 1){
        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the reference rectangle's center x coordinate");
        refx = in.nextDouble();
        refrec.setX(refx);
        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the reference rectangle's center y coordinate");
        refy = in.nextDouble();
        refrec.setY(refy);
        do{
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the reference rectangle's width");
                refwidth = in.nextDouble();
                refrec.setWidth(refwidth);

                ContinueRefWidthLoop = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(refrec.getErrorMessage());
                ContinueRefWidthLoop = true;
            }
        } while (ContinueRefWidthLoop);

        do{
            try{
                System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the reference rectangle's height");
                refheight = in.nextDouble();
                refrec.setHeight(refheight);

                ContinueRefHeightLoop = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(refrec.getErrorMessage());
                ContinueRefHeightLoop = true;
            }
        }while(ContinueRefHeightLoop);

        while(repeatInt2 == 1){

        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test rectangle's center x coordinate");
        testx = in.nextDouble();
        testrec.setX(testx);
        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test rectangle's center y coordinate");
        testy = in.nextDouble();
        testrec.setY(testy);

        do {
            try{
                //Testing loop for test point and rectangle
                System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test rectangle's width");
                testwidth = in.nextDouble();
                testrec.setWidth(testwidth);

                ContinueTestWidthLoop = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(testrec.getErrorMessage());
                ContinueTestWidthLoop = true;
            }
        } while(ContinueTestWidthLoop);

        do{
            try{
                System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test rectangle's height");
                testheight = in.nextDouble();
                testrec.setHeight(testheight);

                ContinueTestHeightLoop = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(testrec.getErrorMessage());
                ContinueTestHeightLoop = true;
            }
        }while(ContinueTestHeightLoop);

        //takes in the test point coordinates
        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test point's x coordinate");
        pointx = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the test point's y coordinate");
        pointy = in.nextDouble();

        //perform all the checks the entered point and rectangle against the reference rectangle
        //checks if test point within reference rectangle
        System.out.println("The reference rectangle's values; " + "\n" + "Center coordinates: (" + refrec.getX() + ", " + refrec.getY() + ")" + "\n" + "Width: " + refrec.getWidth() + "\n" + "Height is: "+ refrec.getHeight() + "\n" + "Area:" + refrec.getArea() + "\n" + "Perimeter: " + refrec.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The test point coordinates are: (" + pointx + ", " + pointy + ")");
        if(refrec.contains(pointx, pointy)){
            System.out.println("----The test point is contained within the reference rectangle!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----The test point is not contained within the reference rectangle");
        }

        System.out.println("The test rectangle's values; " + "\n" + "Center coordinates: (" + testrec.getX() + ", " + testrec.getY() + ")" + "\n" + "Width is: " + testrec.getWidth() + "\n" + "Height is: "+ testrec.getHeight() + "\n" + "Area:" + testrec.getArea() + "\n" + "Perimeter: " + testrec.getPerimeter());
        //checks if test rectangle is within the reference rectangle
        if(refrec.contains(testrec)){
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is within the reference rectangle!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is not within the reference rectangle");
        }
        //checks if test rectangle is overlapping the reference rectangle only if the test rectangle is not contained within the reference rectangle
        if(refrec.overlaps(testrec)){
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is overlapping the reference rectangle!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is not overlapping the reference rectangle");
        }

        //checks if test rectangle is sharing the boundary with the reference rectangle
        if(refrec.abut(testrec)){
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is sharing a boundary with the reference rectangle!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle is not sharing a boundary with the reference rectangle");
        }

        //checks if test rectangle is distinct to the reference rectangle
        if(refrec.distinct(testrec)){
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle and the reference rectangle are distinct!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----The test rectangle and the reference rectangle are not distinct");
        }

        //program loop repeat 
        System.out.println("To reenter a new reference triangle enter 1, to reenter a new test point and new test rectangle enter 2, or to end the program altogether enter 0");

        switch (in.nextInt()) {
        case 1: {
            repeatInt = 1;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            repeatInt2 = 1;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            repeatInt = repeatInt2 = 0;
        }
        }
        }
    }       
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `repeatInt` and `reapeatInt2` are both set to 1 and only will be changed if the user selects to end the program. You need to change these values at the end when they are picking how to restart.

```
switch (in.nextInt()) {
    case 1: {
        repeatInt = 1;
        repeatInt2 = 0; // add this line here
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        repeatInt2 = 1;
        break;
    }
    default: {
        repeatInt = repeatInt2 = 0;
    }
}
```